# How to maintain the state of toggle opened table row using JQuery during an aspx page postback?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, font-awesome

I am trying to use JQuery to toggle open/close three table rows (the `<tr>`'s) with the following scripts, css and html code which were in a asp.net web form page (.aspx). I can click on the plus (+) and minus (-) icons to toggle open the table rows but my problem is that when I click on the "Submit" button that causes a postback and that the opened table row all close and the page is back to its initial state. I wonder if there is a way I can maintain the opened table row state after the postback?

(this code uses jquery-2.2.4.js and font-awesome 4.7.0)

1. JQuery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var $table = $("table");
        $table.find(".activator").click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("open");
        });
    });
</script>
```

2. CSS class:

   .filterTable {margin: auto; border: 0px solid #808080;}
           .activator {cursor: pointer;}
           .activator.open,
           .activator:hover {background: #f8f3ba; border:1px dashed #808080}
           .activator.open .fa-plus-square-o,
           .activator .fa-minus-square-o,
           .activator + .hidden-row {display: none;}
           .activator.open + .hidden-row {display: table-row;}
           .activator.open .fa-minus-square-o {display: inline-block;}
3. HTML code:

   ```
   <div>
       <table class="filterTable">
         <tbody>
           <tr class="activator">
             <td><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i><i class="fa fa-minus-square-o"></i> Row 1</td>
           </tr>
           <tr class="hidden-row">
             <td>Row 1 content<br /> - row 1</td>
           </tr>
           <tr class="activator">
             <td><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i><i class="fa fa-minus-square-o"></i> Row 2</td>
           </tr>
           <tr class="hidden-row">
             <td>Row 2 content<br /> - row 2</td>
           </tr>
           <tr class="activator">
             <td><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i><i class="fa fa-minus-square-o"></i> Row 3</td>
           </tr>
           <tr class="hidden-row">
             <td>Row 3 content<br /> - row 3</td>
           </tr>
          </tbody>
       </table>
       <div style="height:30px;"></div>
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Submit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
   </div>
   ```

Image a - initial page:

[image of the initial state of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJMhf.png)

Image b - toggled opened (when postback this state cannot maintain)

[image of the table-row expanded state of page, which will not maintain after postback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CLlQ.png)

Comment: The HTML code is as below:

Comment: You can use `localStorage` to keep the index of the expanded row. After the page refresh/postback you can read the value and expand accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Harun! Can you provide brief sample as to how to use localStorage in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript function which will called after postback in aspx page

```
function  pageLoad(){
alert('I will be called each time on postback')
//This function will be called on each postback 
//On click on table row you can set the row state in hidden filed  and after postback you can check the hidden filed value to toggle the rows
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Vishwaveer. I will try to use your idea for my problem. My issue is that I am pretty inexperienced in JQuery so even with a good idea I still won't be good enough to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage` to store expanded row's index and after page refresh, read that index and toggle class as following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function storeIndex(index){
       const localStorageArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('expandedRowIndex'));
       if(!localStorageArray){
          localStorageArray = [];
       }

       if(!localStorageArray.includes(index)){
          localStorageArray.push(index)
       }

       localStorage.setItem('expandedRowIndex',JSON.stringify(localStorageArray))


    }

    function removeIndex(index){
       const localStorageArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('expandedRowIndex'));

       if(localStorageArray){
          localStorageArray = localStorageArray.filter(i => i !== index);
          localStorage.setItem('expandedRowIndex',JSON.stringify(localStorageArray))
       }
    }

    $(function () {
        var $table = $("table");
        $table.find(".activator").click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("open");

            const index = $(this).index('.activator')
            if($(this).hasClass("open")){
               storeIndex(index)
            }else{
               removeIndex(index)
            }
        });

        // Read stored index
        const localStorageArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('expandedRowIndex'));

        if(localStorageArray){
            localStorageArray.foreach((index) => {
                $table.find('.activator').eq(index).toggleClass("open");
            })
        }
    });
</script>
```

I haven't tested it yet but it should work fine. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Harun, thank you for your help. I tested your code and it worked! But there is one thing that does not meet my expectation. This works to maintain the "opened" table row just for one row. If I clicked to open two or all three of the rows when postback it only maintains the most recently opened row. Do you have any ideas to make all the "opened" rows keep their open state after postback?

Comment: Hi Harun, it is so nice of you, thank you! I copied your code and did tests in both Internet Explorer and Chrome browser. The new code has issues. First it did not work in IE. When you click on the icon it did not open the hidden row. Secondly, In Chrome browser, you can click to open the hidden rows but when you click on the submit button for a postback the opened rows all closed and the page was back to the initial state.